# How to show return value of a function with Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to use `Angularjs`. How can I show a result of a function in a view?

I have a HTML like this.

```
<body ng-controller="fooCtrl">
  <p>a: {{ a }}</p>
  <p>b: {{ b }}</p>
</body>
```

And javascript for it.

```
fooApp.controller('fooCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
  $scope.a = 3;
  $scope.b = function(){
    return 4;
  };
}]);
```

`a` is properly shown, but `b` is blank. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`b` is a `function object`.  To get result you need to actually call it.

Try

```
<p>b: {{ b() }}</p>
```